# Error in script when I try to render a json

Tags: javascript, json, debugging

I have a bug with my script which produces the following error
[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpI2Z.png)
Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

I have tried to change the format and the json is working fine, it's just the script that gives me the error

Comment: Your `<script>` tag is not JavaScript and the validator is just telling you that. It is meant to check and validate JavaScript only, not HTML (which is what the `<script>` tag is. So removing the HTML/tags and only leaving the JavaScript will get rid of that error. Also, this has nothing to do with JSON so that tag should be removed from the post.

Comment: @EssXTee I agree with you about everything but I would better say that since that's actually json content (as long as I can see from the screenshot shared) maybe it's not correct to use a javascript validator to validate it. JSON has much stricter rules than what javascript requires when defining an object literal.

Comment: oh man I get it, I hadn't thought of that. Thank you very much for helping me